# How to pass sub-class as a parameter to override an abstract method?

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism, overriding, abstract-class

Consider the following abstract class:

I would like to be able to override the abstract `CanBeGroupedWith` method with a derived class of LineContainer and to have everything work. Is this possible?

```
public abstract class LineContainer
{
    public abstract IEnumerable<Line3d> Get3dLines();

    public abstract bool CanBeGroupedWith(LineContainer container);
}

public class DimensionContainer : LineContainer
{        

    public override IEnumerable<Line3d> Get3dLines()
    { //....etc        
    }

    public override bool CanBeGroupedWith(DimensionContainer container)
    {
            /// I want this to be able to work with a DimensionContainer
            /// parameter since the DimensionContainer is in fact 
            /// a LineContainer.
            /// I want to be able to use the DimensionContainer as a
            /// parameter because I want to make use of some specific
            /// fields within it.

            /// I originally tried to have the LineContainer class as a generic class
            /// but I didn't know how to call it while still retaining the CanBeGroupedWith method.
            /// I would then have to specify the type the type in a higher
            /// level class i.e. LineContainer<DimensionContainer> which is
            /// defeats the purpose of the higher level function?                
            /// Any assistance much appreciated 
    }

}
```

Any help or assitance/advice much appreciated

Comment: It does make sense to have something you want. Abstract class is the contract that your derived classes have to implement, it would be problematic if we use abstract class type to reference your derived class instances in this case. You could use generic as you mentioned because in this case you have to be specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use generics to specify that the type has to match the derived type like this.

```
public abstract class LineContainer<T> where T : LineContainer<T>
{
    public abstract IEnumerable<Line3d> Get3dLines();

    public abstract bool CanBeGroupedWith(T container);
}

public class DimensionContainer : LineContainer<DimensionContainer>
{     
    public override IEnumerable<Line3d> Get3dLines()
    {       
    }

    public override bool CanBeGroupedWith(DimensionContainer container)
    {
    }
}
```

Also note that this does not limit the generic type to the derived class it's applied too.  It's just how you can control the type and at least constrain it to a type that does inherit from `LineContainer<T>`.

Comment: thank you for your assistance. But how would I call the LineContainer abstract class in a higher level module - if i had to do this then i would be forced to specify this with a generic - is there a way around this because it seems a little cumbersome?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon If you mean you want to have a `LineContainer` reference to the derived type then yes it would have to specify the derived type as the generic type.  If you want code that can handle different derived type then that code would also have to be generic.  Ultimately at some point you have to specify what derived type is being used.

Answer (score 1):

No. Your comment

> since the DimensionContainer is in fact a LineContainer

is wrong. It might be, or might not be. All you are promised is a LineContainer.

See the contrived class below. Can you really assume that it is a DimensionContainer?

```
public class NotADimensionContainer : LineContainer
{
  // etc        
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var dimensionContainer = new DimensionContainer();
        var canGroup = dimensionContainer.CanBeGroupedWith(new NotADimensionContainer());
    }
}
```